# Error using Zend_Http_Client on GoogleAppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework

I'm developing a web app on Google app engine, using php and zend. 
When I try to run `Zend_Http_Client` to connect to another application on Google app engine written in Java I get an error:

> Unable to Connect to tcp://****.appspot.com:80. Error #-1: Unknown error 4294967295.

Billing is enabled for both applications so everything should work fine. Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: is here anything in the admin console logs? I am guessing a function call is return -1 somewhere.

Comment: No, file_get_contents works fine so I ended up making my own class to take care of connectios...

Answer (score 0):

You can't open arbitrary TCP connections from inside App Engine. See the instructions for [URL Fetch on PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/) here. That would be the correct way to do HTTP requests.